# How to organize a big list with many choices

Tags: selection, dates, choices

We have a situation where a user can select between multiple predefined dates or choose custom dates for reporting purposes.

I'm struggling to brainstorm a flow of how to layout it on a way it shouldn't look like a chunk of data (maybe the break it in conditional groups) and to organize it in a proper way it should be easy for the user.

(A date range picker with predefined dates can't be used since the predefined dates are not absolute dates, but they are relative on when the user runs the report.)

See illustration attached.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear to me whether you are trying to mix sorting and filtering together. When I look at your example "Most recent process date" seems to me sort by time, while the other options filter results within a block of time. You mention that you can't have a date picker, but you have one at the bottom of your example. Would you mind elaborating more on the constrains or limitations you have and what the purpose of your design task is?

Comment: All of the options are about "Filtering", the 'Most recent process date' is the date of the last process.

As for the date picker, I wrote: "A date range picker with predefined dates can't be used since the **predefined** dates are not absolute dates." 

The only absolute date would be the "Custom date" option, all others are relative.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar case and used a text input field with an icon that enabled the user to choose a date by selection, with a set of predefined options (the most common sorting time frames for that use case).

[image]

It works really well here, our users are tech-savvy and they had no problems to use this pattern.

Comment: A date range picker with predefined dates would definitely be my first option. but, as mentioned in my post, it's not applicable in this scenario since the predefined dates are not absolute values, because these dates may be subject to change based on when the user runs the report.